# Build failed with xcode 10 beta

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode10

I created a new project on Xcode beta and built it, It gives me the below build error.

Encountered an error communication with `IBAgent-iOS` on `launchscreen.storyboard`.

The same storyboard error that I am getting when I try to build any sample projects built on Xcode 10 beta.

Has anyone come across the same issue with Xcode 10 beta IDE?

Comment: Did you fix this issue

Answer (score 24):

I face the same issue with `Xcode 10.1`... issue resolved by just clean the build folder using `Command+Shift+K`

[image]

I hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 13):

I'm on Xcode 13 and still get the issue sometimes. No help with cleaning the build folder or removing DerivedData.

However, this usually saves my life ^^

```
sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService
```

Comment: Perfect solution. Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error.
I renamed Xcode from `Xcode-beta` to `Xcode` and it worked for me.

Comment: It worked for me too..!! I renamed xcode 9.4.1 (version current stable) to Xcode_9.4.1 and v10.0 beta to Xcode.!!

Comment: This is applicable for the Xcode10 formal release too!  It seemed irrelevant but it did work when I renamed the old xcode (9.4) to xcode9.4 and renamed xcode10 to xcode.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with xcode 10 installed from the App Store and I tried removing the derived data, cleaning the build folder... nothing worked.

And then I just restarted my computer and it's working. I did not rename anything. It must be some glitch in the memory which is solved after restarting the system.

Comment: Same issue with Xcode10 from App Store. Had to restart computer and it was resolved.

Comment: 2019... still need to restart Mac

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the Targets from that xib, compile and add them back to your xib and compile. It works!

Answer (score 1):

I renamed the

```
Xcode to Xcode10 (from finder > Applications),
```

and then cleaned the build folder

```
(Xcode > Product > Clean Build Folder).
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

- Remove the product file (.app) if old build exits
- Clean the build (Command + Shift + K)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Xcode 11 but still, encounter this problem, I've tried to clean the project and rebuild it but it still won't work. The only solution I found it work is to **uninstall Xcode** and **download the new one from App Store**, this work fine with me and I can use it normally now. I hope this works for you guys too. Cheer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this issue, then I think it is bug of an Xcode 10. The only fix is uninstall your Xcode 10 , and reinstall it again . It will definitely work. This worked for me. Thanks.